# Why is variable undefined in function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have function:

```
def parsePage(url): 
    cur.execute("""UPDATE ap SET status=%s WHERE app='%s'""", (1, url))
```

Where try to make update query in db.

I call function `ParsePage` from another function `parseDetails` as:

```
def parseDetails():
    try:
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM app WHERE status = 0")
        p = multiprocessing.Pool()
        p.map(parsePage, arr)
    ...
```

Why I can access to `cur` in function  `parseDetails()`, but I get error in when I get error: `cur undefined` in line:

```
cur.execute("""UPDATE ap SET status=%s WHERE app='%s'""", (1, url))
```

Comment: Without more context, it's hard to say. Could you add a [mcve]?

Comment: Unless `cur` is a global object, I don't see how you can access it in two different block scoped functions without explicitly passing it into the functions.

Comment: However `p.map` is calling `parsePage`, it does not have access to the same environment as `parseDetails`.

Comment: You won't even get to `parsePage` if you don't get past `cur.execute`, don't know how you can conclude that it won't fail too.

Comment: `cur` is global. I set it in `Connection` function `def connectDB():
    global cur
    global conn`

Comment: Okay, but why it works: `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM app WHERE status = 0")`? Exactly works

Comment: Are these two functions in the same module? Which operating system?

Comment: I get error: ` name 'cur' is not defined`. I use python 3.5 and Windows 10

Comment: You do cur.execute but don't save the result. Then you use some thing called arr. you aren't showing us real code that demonstrates the error which makes it hard to diagnose.

Comment: Under Windows, multiprocessing has to pickle and restore the execution environment. I'm not sure a database connection object will survive that.

Comment: Where I don't save result? I use descriptor `cur` to run queries

Comment: Okay, but I create connection once, and dont close it, so, only change `cursor`